# How can I search for an object property value in an array if I only know a different property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

In this array I would like to find the `id` of the object by querying on the property `name`. Given I know the `name` is `NV`, how can I get the `id`?

I already tried different loops and other thing like `GetObject`, but it gives no return.

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "BV",
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "NV"
    }
  ],
}
```

Comment: What is `GetObject`?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [`array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
var data = {
  "items": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "BV",
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "NV"
    }
  ],
};

console.log(data.items.find(item => item.name == "NV").id)
```

Comment: Very nice, however it's important to consider the absence of support for es5 and below. The MDN article does indeed provide a polyfill.

Answer (score 0):

> programming in JSON

What? JSON is *always* just a string - it is the string representation of various forms of data; nothing more.

If you have some JSON and you want to read some data from it, or manipulate it, first you will want to convert the JSON to usable data

But before that you have to fix your BROKEN JSON – you have trailing commas that are not valid

```
var brokenjson = '{"items": [{"id": 1, "name": "BV",},{"id": 2,"name": "NV"}],}'

var goodjson   = '{"items": [{"id": 1, "name": "BV"},{"id": 2,"name": "NV"}]}'
```

Now that your JSON is fixed, we can get what you're looking for

```js
var json = '{"items": [{"id": 1, "name": "BV"},{"id": 2,"name": "NV"}]}'

var data = JSON.parse(json)

// get id from items where name is 'NV'
console.log(data.items.find(x => x.name === 'NV').id) // 2
```

---

If you don't have `Array.prototype.find`, just make it

```
Array.prototype.find = function find (f, context) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
    if (f.call(context || window, this[i], i, this))
      return this[i]
}
```

Comment: Good work avoiding unnecessary curly brackets. But `return undefined` is a no-op,.

Comment: @torazaburo yeah I thought about that, I just thought it looked weird without an explicit return value – probably just a habit I've formed somewhere. I'll remove it ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array [**filter()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method :

```js
var jsonObj = {
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "BV",
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "NV"
    }
  ]
};

var res = jsonObj.items.filter(function(item) {
    return item.name == "NV";
});

console.log(res[0].id);
```

Comment: `filter` iterates through the entire data set even if a match is found early on. If it was a large data set, that would be extremely inefficient.